# How to convert diagonal rows into single row in R?

Tags: r, row

I have a `dataset1` which is as follows:

```
dataset1 <- data.frame(  
   id1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),    
   id2 = c(122, 122, 122, 133, 133, 133),  
   num1 = c(1, NA, NA, 50,NA, NA),  
   num2 = c(NA, 2, NA, NA, 45, NA),  
   num3 = c(NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 4)  
 )
```

How to convert multiple rows into a single row?

The desired output is:

```
id1, id2, num1, num2, num3   
1    122   1     2      3      
2    133   50    45     4
```

Comment: `library(dplyr); dataset1 %>% group_by(id1, id2) %>% summarise_all(funs(sum(.,na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: using `diag` : `dataset1 %>% group_by(id1,id2) %>% do(data.frame(t(diag(as.matrix(.[-(1:2)])))))`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)

dataset1 %>% group_by(id1, id2) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(.[!is.na(.)])) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#   id1 id2 num1 num2 num3
# 1   1 122    1    2    3
# 2   2 133   50   45    4
```

Note: Assuming there will be only `1` non-NA item in a column.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
data.table(dataset1)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by = c("id1", "id2")]

#   id1 id2 num1 num2 num3
#1:   1 122    1    2    3
#2:   2 133   50   45    4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` to achieve that:

```
library(dplyr)
dataset1 %>% 
  group_by(id1, id2) %>% 
  mutate(
    num1 = sum(num1, na.rm=T),
    num2 = sum(num2, na.rm=T),
    num3 = sum(num3, na.rm=T)
  ) %>% 
  distinct()
```

Output:

[image]

This is also assuming if there's a repeated value in any of the variable we're going to sum it (if `id1 = 1` has **two values** for `num1`, we're going to sum the value). If you're confident that every `id` has only one possible value for each of the num (num1 to num3), then don't worry about it.